# Wildcard search not searching result as expected

Tags: wildcard, marklogic-10

In the marklogic database configuration, the three-character wildcard option is enabled. However, when I execute following queries:

```
cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("namespace","text"), "ii*", ("punctuation-sensitive","whitespace-sensitive","lang=en"), 1) 

cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("namespace","text"), "ii?", ("punctuation-sensitive","whitespace-sensitive","lang=en"), 1)
```

It retrieves XML documents containing the text "Group I" in the text node. Strangely, when I enable two-character search, the query behaves as expected and does not retrieve the document containing "Group I" in the text node.

Can someone suggest, why this issue arises when the wildcard is used?